# XCode One-Click Enterprise Distribution Sharing

Tags: xcode, testing

I am using XCode for iOS app development for long and while develop apps, I use enterprise sharing mechanism to test the app on my device every time I need to test it up.

The steps I do are as follows:

1. Clean Project
2. Build for Archiving
3. Archive (Organizer window pops up)
4. On Organizer window, clicking Share
5. Selecting Content and Options for Sharing
6. Ticking checkbox of "Save for Enterprise Distribution"
7. Filling top 2 fields (Application URL & Title)
8. Saving
9. Putting generated 2 files (app.ipa & app.plist) inside intranet folder so I can access it from the device with http://my_mac/app/index.html

Although this works but the process is so time consuming for every test I need to make. So I was wondering if there is a way I can write a XCode plugin or something that would put an extra button inside Build menu which may read "Run on Device" and would do that whole job for me instantly. What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://testflightapp.com

Comment: Well this seems one solution, but I can't use it on my jailbroken phone.

Comment: My phone is jailbroken too, it works. You mean that you don't have a developer account?

Comment: I have developer account. When I try to install their stuff from app store, it give me an error.

Comment: It always says "Your iPhone is not activated." I had a thread sometime ago there as well http://support.testflightapp.com/discussions/problems/1056-this-iphone-is-not-activated